# Github actions suddenly throwing "no version specified" for reusable workflows that worked yesterday

Tags: github, github-actions, github-actions-workflows

I'm not sure if this is a bug or a breaking change happened as of yesterday, I have a pretty simple setup calling three reusable workflows:

```yaml
name: pr-checks

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: "**"

jobs:
  lint:
    name: Call Lint
    uses: ./.github/checks/check-lint.yaml

  test:
    name: Call Test
    uses: ./.github/checks/check-test.yaml

  e2e:
    name: Call E2E
    uses: ./.github/checks/check-e2e.yaml
```

But this throws

```
"invalid value workflow reference: no version specified"
```

as of now, even though identical workflows have worked yesterday.

When reusing workflows like this at the 'job' level - it is not necessary to specify version, in fact, it used to error out if I specified the version.

Screenshots attached as I think this doesn't make much sense.

[image]

I did click on 're-run all jobs and it re-ran successfully.

However, without any discenrable difference and after also removing the build step just to be sure there's nothing weird happening there:

[image]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As you can see in your 2 screenshots, one is referring to the `.github/workflows` directory (the one which worked), and the other to the `.github/checks` directory (the one which didn't).

*Short answer:* **If you change the workflow folder back to `workflows` instead of `checks`, it should work as expected.**

---

*Long answer:* It seems there is a confusion between the syntax of two different concepts:

- [local actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-an-action-in-the-same-repository-as-the-workflow) (using an action in the same repo)
- [reusable workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows) (reusing the same workflow in different workflows)

##### LOCAL ACTIONS

To access **local actions** (folders with `action.yml` file) from your workflow, you need to use the `actions/checkout` first, to allow it to access the other repository folders and files.

**Example:**

```
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3 # Necessary to access local action
      - name: Local Action Call
        uses: ./.github/actions/local-action #path/to/action
```

*I've made a POC [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/36-local-action.yml) some time ago if you want to have a look.*

##### REUSABLE WORKFLOWS

Now, if you want to use **reusable workflows**, the issue is different:

> As with other workflow files, you locate reusable workflows in the
> **`.github/workflows` directory** of a repository. Subdirectories of the
> workflows directory are not supported.

[GitHub documentation reference](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#creating-a-reusable-workflow)

In that case, according to this [other section from the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#calling-a-reusable-workflow):

> You reference reusable workflow files using one of the following
> syntaxes:
>
> **`{owner}/{repo}/.github/workflows/{filename}@{ref}`** for reusable
> workflows in public repositories.
>
> `./.github/workflows/{filename}` for reusable workflows in the same repository.
>
> `{ref}` can be a **SHA**, a **release tag**, or a **branch name**.

**Example:**

```
  lint:
    name: Call Lint
    uses: ./.github/workflows/check-lint.yaml@{SHA/TAG/BRANCH}
```

or

```
  lint:
    name: Call Lint
    uses: ./.github/workflows/check-lint.yaml
```

Here is another POC for the [workflow call](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/34-workflow-call.yml) using this [reusable workflow](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/33-reusable-workflow.yml)

---

##### CONCLUSION

It's like you were trying to call a reusable workflow as if it was a local action, which won't work as reusable workflows need to be located in the `.github/workflows` directory.

*Note that you could eventually add the `@branch-name` at the end of the workflow call to be sure to use the workflow from the branch you want to test if the reusable workflow is already present on the default branch.*

Comment: Just a note, it does need to be in the root of the `workflows` directory, you cannot do something like `workflows/actions/my-file.yml`

Comment: i am kinda confuse when try this it says like like i was trying reate resualbale jjobs but in action but it keeps saying action must be define does that mean i should define this at only action only!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Share your context in a new question `bhupesh` so that we can analyze it :)