# How to reference another yml file from the main github action yaml file?

Tags: yaml, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm defining a github action script that's referencing to another yaml file, hoping to put the configuration into a more organised way.

Here is my job file, named as `deploy.yml` in the path of `./.github/workflows/`, where the first `.` is the root folder of my project.

```
....
jobs:
  UnitTest:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: ./.github/workflows/unittest.yml
```

In the same `./.github/workflows/` folder, I created another file called `unittest.yml` as below:

```
name: "UnitTest"
description: "Perform Unit Test"
runs:
  # using: "composite"
  - name: Dependency
    run: |
      echo "Dependency setup commands go here"

  - name: UnitTest
    run: make test.unit
```

However, when I tried to test the script locally using [act](https://github.com/nektos/act) with command `act --secret-file .secrets --container-architecture linux/amd64`, I received the following error:

```
[Deploy/UnitTest]   ✅  Success - Main actions/checkout@v3
[Deploy/UnitTest] ⭐ Run Main ./.github/workflows/unittest.yml
[Deploy/UnitTest]   ❌  Failure - Main ./.github/workflows/unittest.yml
[Deploy/UnitTest] file does not exist
[Deploy/UnitTest]   Job failed
```

I have tried to put just the file name `unittest.yml` or `./unittest.yml` or `myrepo_name/.github/workflows/unittest.yml` or put the file into a subfolder like [step 2 of this document](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#using-inputs-and-secrets-in-a-reusable-workflow) illustrated, but all no luck.

Based on examples of [runs for composition actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#runsstepsuses), I would imagine this should work.

Would anyone please advise?

P.S. You might have noticed the commented line of `using: "composite"` in the `unittest.yml`. If I uncomment the line, I'll receive error:

```
Error: yaml: line 3: did not find expected key
```

Comment: The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73026597/github-actions-suddenly-throwing-no-version-specified-for-reusable-workflows-t) could give you some insights about what may be happening.

Answer (score 6):

Composite actions are not referenced by YAML file, but a folder. In that folder, you are expected to have an action.yml describing the action.

This is why you're getting the error with `using: composite`, you're defining a workflow (because it's in `./github/workflows`), but you are using action syntax.

I would advise this folder structure:

```
.github/
 |-- workflows/
    | -- deploy.yml
unittest-action/
 |-- action.yml
```

With this structure, you should be able to reference the action with

```yaml
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
- uses: ./unittest-action
```

Please see the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action) for more information.

---

Depending on your use-case and setup, you might also want to consider [reusable workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows).

You can define a reusable workflow in your `.github/workflows` directory like so:

```yaml
# unittest.yml
on: workflow_call

jobs:
  deploy:
    # ...
```

and then call it like so:

```yaml
jobs:
  UnitTest:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/unittest.yml
```

Note how the reusable workflow is an entire job. This means, you can't do the checkout from the outside and then just run the unit test in the reusable job. The reusable job (unittest.yml) needs to do the checkout first.

---

Which one to pick?

Here's a [blog post](https://dev.to/n3wt0n/composite-actions-vs-reusable-workflows-what-is-the-difference-github-actions-11kd#:%7E:text=With%20Reusable%20workflows%20you%20have,if%20it%20contains%20multiple%20steps.) summarising some of the differences between composite actions and reusable workflows, like:

- reusable workflows can contain several jobs, composite actions only contain steps
- reusable workflows have better support for using secrets
- composite actions can be nested, but as of Jul '22, reusable workflows can't call other reusable workflows

Comment: "you can't do the checkout from the outside" - that's not completely true

Comment: Please elaborate :)

Comment: I haven't yet tried to implement it but this certainly clarifies a lot of my doubts. Thank you.

Comment: Just a suggestion @rethab: It would be nice to add the explanation that you need to use the `- uses: actions/checkout@v3` in the workflow accessing the composite actions, otherwise it doesn't have access to the repo folder with the `action.yml` file (I know it's on the documentation, but it would be a nice addition to your answer )

Comment: @Lee please accept the answer if it fixes your problem.