# Error running reusable workflows - Github actions

Tags: azure, github, github-actions

I want to use reusable workflows and invoke two other actions, below is the snippet of both caller and called workflows:

***az-dev-img-ops-reusable.yml (called workflow1)***

```
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      cloudProvider:
        required: true
        type: string
      imgAction: 
        required: true
        type: string
      envName: 
        required: true
        type: string
      productImage: 
        required: true
        type: string        
jobs:
  image-actions:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: ./.github/workflows/manage_images
        with:
          imgAction: ${{ inputs.imgAction }}
          cloudProvider: ${{ inputs.cloudProvider }} 
          envName: ${{ inputs.envName }}
          productImage: ${{ inputs.productImage }}
```

***az-dev-tenant-ops-reusable.yml (called workflow2)***

```
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      cloudProvider:
        required: true
        type: string
      envName: 
        required: true
        type: string    
      action: 
        required: true
        type: string      
jobs:
  tenant-actions:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: ./.github/workflows/refresh_tenant
        with: 
          cloudProvider: azure
          envName: az-dev
          action: pod_refresh
```

***az-dev-cicd.yml (caller workflow)***

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  init:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
  image-operations:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/az-dev-img-ops-reusable.yml
    with:
      imgAction: check 
      cloudProvider: azure 
      envName: az-dev 
      productImage: my-server
  tenant-operations:
    needs: image-operations
    uses: ./.github/workflows/az-dev-tenant-ops-reusable.yml
    with: 
      cloudProvider: azure
      envName: az-dev
      action: pod_refresh
```

But while running, it throws error as below:

```
Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile' under '/opt/my-runner/_work/my-images/my-images/.github/workflows/manage_images'. Did you forget to run actions/checkout before running your local action?
```

Checked over the web for solutions and tried all i.e.

1. Have a actions/checkout.
2. Make sure the caller function makes use of "uses" and not steps.
3. Tried both absolute path of repo/yaml and relative path.

But haven't been able to resolve it. Any hints/help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try moving the `.github/workflows/manage_images` to another directory instead? Example: `.github/manage_images` directly, as it may be having conflicts with the `.github/workflows` directory.

Comment: @GuiFalourd I want to leverage other action files once this starts working. Hence, I cannot move them to another directory. Ideally, in the docs also it states that all yaml files should reside under .github/workflows. Also, subdirectories inside it is restricted I believe.

Comment: Just checked it here and indeed, the action.yaml being in a `.github/workflows` subdirectory isn't an issue here. Does it also happen without using self-hosted runners?

Comment: Could you also share the `./.github/workflows/manage_images` directory structure / files in the question, to reproduce the full behavior please?

Comment: @GuiFalourd The tree structure can be found under https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnbam.jpg

Comment: Ok. There is your issue: When using local actions, you need to create a `action.yaml` file in a directory. In your case, you won't use the `manage_images.yaml` workflow, you should use a `manage_images` folder with the `action.yaml` file in it. Now, if this `manage_images.yaml` is a reusable workflow, you need to add `.yaml` at the end of the `uses: ./.github/workflows/manage_images` line. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73026597/github-actions-suddenly-throwing-no-version-specified-for-reusable-workflows-t/73026906#73026906) could give you more context.

Comment: Great, it works ! But unable to understand if this directory structure is a mandate for running reusable workflows. Will it not work if I directly provide the file path location i.e. ./.github/workflows/manage_images.yml ?

Comment: Great, I'll add it as official answer  I don't know your `manage_images.yaml` file implementation, so I can't say if you could use it as reusable workflow instead of as an action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you used the following syntax:

```
uses: ./.github/workflows/manage_images
```

... that refers to a **directory**.

When used that way, the Github Action interpreter expect a [local action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-an-action-in-the-same-repository-as-the-workflow) *(using an action in the same repo)*.

However, to use `local actions`, you need to create a `action.yaml` file in a directory, but in your case, [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnbam.jpg) you shared in the comment shows that you actually have a `manage_images.yaml` file, that refers to a **workflow**, not a `manage_images` folder with an `action.yml` file in it.

To resolve your issue, if this `manage_images.yaml` is a [reusable workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows) *(reusing the same workflow in different workflows)*, you need to add `.yaml` at the end of **uses** step, like this:

```
uses: ./.github/workflows/manage_images.yaml
```

Or, if you actually want to use a local action, convert this `manage_images.yaml` workflow to an action.yaml file, and put it inside a `.github/workflows/manage_images` directory.

*Note that this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73026597/github-actions-suddenly-throwing-no-version-specified-for-reusable-workflows-t/73026906#73026906) could also give you more context about local actions and reusable workflows.*