# Let workflow call other workflow

Tags: yaml, continuous-integration, github-actions

So I'm testing something where I have a main workflow which I want to call another workflow. This is just a simple test I'm doing.
workflow 1:

```
name: main workflow
on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  call-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: test
        uses: ./.github/workflows/test.yaml
```

So I want my main workflow to call the test workflow

Test workflow:

```
name: test workflow
on: workflow_call
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: test
        run: echo "test"
```

But for some reason I keep getting this error.

```
Error: Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile' under '/home/runner/work/internship2023-solarstreaming/internship2023-solarstreaming/.github/workflows/test.yaml'. Did you forget to run actions/checkout before running your local action?
```

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your [reusable workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#creating-a-reusable-workflow) isn't configured correctly.

Instead of:

```
name: test workflow
on: workflow_call
jobs:
  test:
    [ ... ]
```

You need the trigger `on` field to be configured like this:

```
name: test workflow
on: 
  workflow_call:
jobs:
  test:
    [ ... ]
```

---

**Observations**

Regarding the other workflow, you don't even need the `actions/checkout` and the job **runner** (`runs-on` filed) configured there, just using it as below will work:

```
name: main workflow
on: [push, pull_request]
jobs:
  call-test:
    steps:
      - uses: ./.github/workflows/test.yaml
```

*Note: You need to specify the job **runner** and use the `actions/checkout` action when you're trying to call a [local action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-an-action-in-the-same-repository-as-the-workflow), which is not the case here as you specified another workflow file, not a folder. For more informations about the difference, I suggest [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73026597/github-actions-suddenly-throwing-no-version-specified-for-reusable-workflows-t/73026906#73026906)*

Comment: `on: workflow_call` should also work fine.